# Как исправить ошибку invalid argument supplied for foreach()?

Tags: php

**Добрый день. Как исправить ошибку invalid argument supplied for foreach()?**

```
<?php require 'db.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div class="other-fac">

        <?php
                                    
            if (class_exists('active')) {
                global $teacher_all;
    
                if (class_exists('Add_education')) {
                    $this->get_Faculty_Add_education();
    
                } elseif (class_exists('Ec_and_Management')) {
                    $this->get_Faculty_Ec_and_Managementt(); 
    
                } elseif (class_exists('Fac_of_low')) {
                    $this->get_Fac_of_low();
    
                } elseif (class_exists('Fac_of_low')) {
                    $this->get_Fac_of_tr_and_technology();
            }
        } ; ?> 

    </div>

    <div class="list-teacher">

        <?php
            global $teachers_all;
        
            foreach ($teachers_all as $teacher): ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Только начинаю изучать php, поэтому по синтаксису тоже готов послушать, что подправить и что лучше использовать. Не стал вставлять весь код, ограничился парой div и самим кодом php для понимания.

other-fac используется для выбора пункта меню слева, которое получает class active в зависимости от того нажат или нет.

list-teacher используется для отображения информации из базы данных.

Буду рад любой помощи :)**

Comment: За global надо сразу по рукам бить)

Comment: только начинаю изучать) обойдёмся предупреждением :)))

Comment: В любом случае непонятно, что находится в `$teachers_all`, скорее всего не массив или коллекция, отчего и ругается

Comment: фото с базы данных
https://ibb.co/KVwg8pJ

фото переменной get_Faculty_Ec_and_Management() (дальше только значения другие)
https://ibb.co/QDZ0BX8

Comment: Но это не даёт ответ на вопрос. Но появляется новый: откуда в функции на Вашем скрине взялась переменная `$teacher`? Что Вы пытаетесь вернуть? Результат запроса записан в другую переменную.